# Possible to find roots of a function involving heaviside?

Tags: special-functions, roots

Consider the function

$f(t) = 3+t-(t-3)^2\theta(t-3)$,

where $\theta(t)$ is the heaviside step function.

Can i solve the equation $f(t) = 0$ somehow?

Comment: You should include the definition of $\theta$ in the problem statement. But if it's what I think it is, then it's defined by two different expressions on two different regions for $t$; I don't think there's any better way to solve your equation than to consider those two regions separately.

Comment: in other words, for $t < 3$, $f(t) = 3 + t$; for $t \ge 3$, $f(t) = 3 + t - (t - 3)^2$. Solve them separately. Throw out any root that is outside the domain where its function is used. The remaining roots are your solution.